Matching enum variant without specifying variants in Rust macro
I am trying to use enum variants to store variables specific to tabs in an app. I am using the below code to extract the variable out of the enum. (because accessing a variant directly doesn't work, for example self.selection doesn't work)
enum Tab {
    StrokeProperties { selection: [bool; 2] },
    Canvas {},
    Library {},
}

let selection = match self { // `self` refers to `Tab`
    Tab::StrokeProperties { selection, .. } => { selection }
    _ => { !unreachable!() }
}

I want to use a macro to avoid having to write it every time. However it doesn't seem to work.
macro_rules! enum_get {
    ($matched_variant:expr, $matched_enum:expr, $field:ident) => {
        match $matched_variant {
            $matched_enum { $field, .. } => { $field },
            _ => { !unreachable!() }
        }
    }
}
...
enum_get!(self, Tab::StrokeProperties, selection); // Ideally I would also be able to remove the reference to `Tab::StrokeProperties` entirely, but I don't understand macros well enough to do that.

  --> src\ui.rs:9:27
   |
9  |             $matched_enum { $field, .. } => { $field },
   |                           ^ expected one of `...`, `..=`, `..`, `=>`, `if`, or `|`
...
65 |                             let selection = enum_get!(self, Tab::StrokeProperties, selection);
   |                                             ------------------------------------------------- in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `enum_get` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

I managed to get it working kind of, with the following code. But it isn't a nice macro, and barely cuts down on code.
macro_rules! enum_get {
    ($matched_variant:expr, $matched_enum:pat, $field:ident) => {
        match $matched_variant {
            $matched_enum => { $field },
            _ => { !unreachable!() }
        }
    }
}
...
enum_get!(self, Tab::StrokeProperties { selection, .. }, selection);

Is it possible to make it work without the curly brackets ({ selection, .. }) in the macro call or completely remove Tab::StrokeProperties from the macro call?

Use path not expr for matched_enum: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cf93fb4410b110ffd3f4b5a17ce59829 Also, you don't need an ! in front of unreachable!(), that means logical not and produces an additional warning.

To answer your first question, it is possible to remove the curly bracket section. It requires matching the enum variant (Tab::StrokeProperties) as a path not an expr or complete pattern. Documentation of available macro_rules! argument types can be found here. Here is the working code:
enum Tab {
    StrokeProperties { selection: [bool; 2] },
    Canvas {},
    Library {},
}

macro_rules! enum_get {
    ($matched_variant:expr, $matched_enum:path, $field:ident) => {
        match $matched_variant {
            $matched_enum { $field, .. }=> { $field },
            _ => { unreachable!() }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tab = Tab::StrokeProperties{selection: [false; 2]};
    let selection = enum_get!(tab, Tab::StrokeProperties, selection);
    println!("{selection:?}"); // [false, false]
}

To answer your second question, it is not possible to remove Tab::StrokeProperties entirely, because the macro has no way of knowing which enum variants/fields exist, unless you made a more complex macro that consumed the entire enum Tab { ... } item.

I'm going to call the macro an XY problem.
A far simpler approach would be to provide conversion methods, like:
enum Tab {
    StrokeProperties { selection: [bool; 2] },
    Canvas {},
    Library {},
}

impl Tab {
    pub fn as_stroke_properties(self) -> Option<[bool; 2]> {
        match self {
            Self::StrokeProperties { selection } => Some(selection),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

Now your usage site becomes:
let selection = self.as_stroke_properties().unwrap();

In this case, the methods could probably take &self instead of self. You'll have to decide which makes more sense.
It may also be beneficial to split the payload out into its own type, so that you can deal with that as a single value:
enum Tab {
    StrokeProperties(StrokeProperties),
    Canvas {},
    Library {},
}

struct StrokeProperties {
    selection: [bool; 2],
}

impl Tab {
    pub fn as_stroke_properties(self) -> Option<StrokeProperties> {
        match self {
            Self::StrokeProperties(p) => Some(p),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

